# Calculating a total while writing out a table in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating one jsp page in which I read in a text file, then display that data in tabular format. Now I need to calculate a total.

I am reading the file using `BufferedReader`, then writing the output like this:

```
 String fileName = "C:\\M2011001582.TXT";
 BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
 int lineCount=1;
 String fileData = "";
 out.println("<table border=\"1\" ><thead>"
   + "<tr><th>  SNO </th>"
   + "<th>  Batch Number </th>"
   + "<th>  amount </th>"...</tr>);
 while((fileData = is.readLine()) != null)
 {
   out.println( "<tr>"
     + "<td>" + lineCount++ + "</td>"
     + "<td>" + fileData.substring(0,6) + "</td>" //batch no
     + "<td>" + fileData.substring(6,14) + "</td></tr>" ); //amount...
  }
```

The output displays 4 rows and 2 columns. How can I calculate the total amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the java code in service and call this service from Controller and just pass calculated data to view (jsp) to render

See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servlets)

Comment: thanks to reply me..i m using netbeans...i m little bit confused and i m weak in java programming..plz can u explain me in detail